# Write to Linux sysfs node in C

Tags: c, linux

From the shell I can activate the leds on my system like this:

```
#echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/NAME:COLOR:LOCATION/brightness
```

I want to do the exact same thing from a C program, but I have not been able to find a simple example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the sysfs node like a file, write '1' to it, and close it again.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void enable_led() {
  int fd;
  char d = '1';
  fd = open("sys/class/leds/NAME:COLOR:LOCATION/brightness", O_WRONLY);
  write (fd, &d, 1);
  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: This definitely will get me started. Just one more question, would it be possible to use a variable instead of the full path in the open routine?

Comment: Sure - change to enable_led(char *pathname) and open(pathname, O_WRONLY) then call if from somewhere else as enable_led("/sys/whatever")

Comment: IN which Space will the app work.Driver is running in the kernel mode.Do we have to compile this as a module or something.

Comment: No, this is a method for a normal user mode program (but probably a privileged one) to set small amounts of data into a kernel driver.

Comment: Is there any difference between your solution vs using `fopen()` from standard C library?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("/sys/class/leds/NAME:COLOR:LOCATION/brightness", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open path for writing\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(f, "1\n");
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not booted into my linux partition, but I suspect it goes something like this:

```
int f = open("/sys/class/leds/NAME:COLOR:LOCATION/brightness",O_WRONLY);
if (f != -1)
{
    write(f, "1", 1);
    close(f);
}
```