# Interface Bonding (aggregation) in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, interface, network-programming, linux-kernel

We usually use interfaces or sysfs or ifenslave in linux (Ubuntu) to configure bonding interfaces for aggregating two or more NIC cards. Then, there is netlink library that allows us to create and delete bonds and add and remove interfaces from it. But what it currently doesn't offer is changing the other properties of the bond dynamically.

For example, I want to change the MTU or the Hardware Address of the bond, or its bonding mode itself. This information usually resides in

```
 /sys/class/net/bondx/...
```

and in bonding_masters and we need to do something like

```
 # ifconfig bond0 down
 echo 6 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode
```

to change its bonding mode to balance-alb dynamically, i.e. without reboot or restarting networking by altering the interfaces files. Similarly we can alter other parameters given in the documentation that accompanies the bonding module

But if I were to change it through an interactive C program, how do I interface with the sysfs? I have no prior experience with interfacing with file systems directly except the basic file handling in C. Developers are a no-no to libsysfs and I read somewhere that libudev might be useful but I am not too sure. So like sysctl() is for /proc file systems, what is the interface for sysfs file systems?

Or are there other programmatic methods to go about this problem? Maybe ioctl?

Comment: I think the answer is here : [Write to Linux sysfs node in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458166/write-to-linux-sysfs-node-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could write to `/sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode` using `echo` from the shell, you could also write to it using `write()` from a program.

Answer (score 1):

In linux/ubuntu/Debian you can simply use **$ip link [options]** command to accomplish your task.
Change or modify the bonding options by using

***$ip link set dev bond0 type bond mode mode_name***

and

you can see all the options available to modify the bond interface by typing

***$ip link set dev bond0 type bond --help***

here you will find all possible bonding options, which can be used for further modification.